# Keep materialized value type in akka stream divertTo or alsoTo

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I try to create a kafka consumer stream which has a Source of type
`Source<ConsumerMEssage.CommittableMessage<String,String>, Consumer.Control`.

from this source I want to use different pathes based on some predicates.
Therefore I'd like to use the `divertTo` method and sometimes the `alsoTo` method.

Both methods are accepting a Sink. My problem is that when I build this Sink I want to have the Sink to have the materialzed value type `Consumer.Control` which is provided by the source.
What I'm doing right now is building the sink like this

```
private Sink<SomeType, NotUsed> sinkForPathA(){
  Flow.of(SomeType.class)
    .to(Committer.sink(committerSettings));
}
```

As you may noticed the materialized value type is now NotUsed which is not desired. What I'd like to have is this:

```
private Sink<SomeType, Consumer.DrainingControl> sinkForPathA(){
  Flow.of(SomeType.class)
    .toMat(Committer.sink(committerSettings),Consumer::createDrainingControl);
}
```

Is it somehow possible to create a Flow with a predefined materialized value type and not just `NotUsed`?

Comment: Did you mean `diverTo`, or `divertTo`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the type. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly create a `Flow` with materialized value of the inner `Sink`.

Taking `Sink.seq()` which has materialized value type: `CompletionStage<List<T>>` as an example.

If you say create a `Flow` like this:

```
Flow.of(Integer.class)
    .to(Sink.seq());
```

then as you pointed out you'll ge `NotUsed` in the returned `Sink`. The trick is to use `toMat` with `keepRight` to retain the materialized value type of the `Sink`. It would go like this:

```
Flow.of(Integer.class)
    .toMat(Sink.seq(), Keep.right());
```

and now you'll get `Sink<Integer, CompletionStage<List<Integer>>>` as a result.